# Защитить файл php от просмотра пользователей

Tags: ajax, php

Как защитить файл php от просмотра пользователей, но нет от ajax запросов?

Comment: от просмотра - то есть, что бы не могли смотреть иcходник? но тогда что делает ajax запрос? он ведь его не выполнит. То есть, эти вещи взаимоисключающие.

Или Вы хотите, что бы только ajax запросы могли выполнять код, а прямой запрос через браузер - нет?

Comment: есть php файл .надо чтобы если к нему напрямую обращаешься выдовал ошибку через php это сделать легко но тогда ajax запрос не выполняется

Comment: @ahserg, вы только не надейтесь, что эта идея обеспечивает какую-то защиту

Comment: ... потому что тот, кто и вправду захочет посмотреть на файл, уж сможет подделать заголовки.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно принять тот факт, что запрос через ajax делается тем же браузером, поэтому отличить эти запросы сложно. Но никто не мешает добавить в запрос дополнительные параметры, а php их проверит. та же сессия, те же куки.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать таким образом проверять:

```
if(isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && ( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' )){
    // это ajax-запрос
}
```